# How to delete Integration Account for Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Where can I find some information regarding how to delete or remove Integration Account for Logic App? If I remove all my Logic App, does it automatically removes the Logic App Integration account service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Integration Account is a separate Resource from all Logic Apps.

To delete an Integration Account, you select the Integration Account, then press Delete in the button banner near the top.

Answer (score 1):

Integration account is a separate component. you can link/unlink it to your logic app in Azure portal. just open your logic app instance, click `Settings\Workflow settings\Integration account` to find the itegration account instance. 
[image]

If you want to delete the integration account, just find it under integration Account category.